# ShareDialog isn't showed when sharing a link to facebook from android application

Tags: java, android, facebook, mobile

I had an android application call **Health** with FacebookApp sharing feature. It's working right with FacebookApp_A (when I click to share, it shows sharedialog).

I want replace FacebookApp_A by FacebookApp_B.

Step 1: I create FacebookApp_B, define PackageName, ClassName, turn on (Yes) feature **Single Sign On**, make it to General public status.

Step 2: I use this code to get HashKey and I got it.

try {

```
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("<--app Health package name -->",PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}
```

Step 3: I change facebook_app_id in Manifest.xml to FacebookApp_B's Id.

Step 4: I build my project to .apk file with file **debug.keystore of Education App because I lost Health App's keystore.**

Step 5: I setup Health App and click to share a link to facebook. At this time, a confirm dialog is showed on the screen:

**AppName would like to access your public profile and friend list**

Step 6: I click OK but the ShareDialog is not showed.

Everything works right with FacebookApp_A but not with FacebookApp_B and I don't know what I had missed.

I want show the ShareDialog like using FacebookApp_A.

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0):

Check if the facebook app you are using in android app to share is not in sandbox mode .

Answer (score 0):

If you've created a new facebook app then you also have to generate the **hashKey** as well. Once you have get the hash key then insert in the facebook app settings. To generate the hash key properly please follow the steps in facebook developer guide.

[Facebook Developer Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started)

The below code snippet is taken from the facebook developer guide section [[4]](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started)

```
public void printHashKey() {

   // Add code to print out the key hash
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook", 
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
}
```

Insert the generated **hashKey** in the facebook app settings as shown below:

[image]

Comment: I had set my facebookapp to general public status and get KeyHash but nothing is changed. :(

Comment: Can you please confirm that you have given the facebook sharing permissions **publish_actions** for your app in the android code? Check the facebook guide for sharing permissions - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share/. Let me know, if it works for you now.